# What does `|` do in this object in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm browsing [the docs for Facebook's `Flow`](https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html), and I can't figure out some of this syntax.

I know `|` is a bitwise `OR` operator, and while I'm not 100% on what that does, it doesn't appear to make sense when used with `strings`.

Is this syntax unique to `Flow` in the `React` ES6 class construction?

And while I'm at it: what does `props: Props` accomplish?

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  props: Props;

  state: {
    display: 'static' | 'hover' | 'active';
  };

  static defaultProps: { visited: boolean };

  onMouseEnter: () => void;
  onMouseLeave: () => void;
  onMouseDown: () => void;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      display: 'static',
    };

    const setDisplay = display => this.setState({display});

    this.onMouseEnter = () => setDisplay('hover');
    this.onMouseLeave = () => setDisplay('static');
    this.onMouseDown = () => setDisplay('active');
  }

  render() {
    let className = 'button ' + this.state.display;
    if (this.props.visited) {
      className += ' visited';
    }

    return (
      <div className={className}
        onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.title}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `|` is bit-wise OR, meaning that it takes only integer values. Since you're using strings, it coerces them to integers using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), which returns `NaN`, and when OR-ed together, produces `0`.

Comment: @4castle this is some sort of weird-o Flow thing; it's a different syntax layered over JavaScript. Specifically I think it's a [disjoint union](https://flowtype.org/docs/disjoint-unions.html#_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [Union](https://flowtype.org/docs/union-intersection-types.html#syntax) in Flow. In the case above, it doesn't appear to be a bitwise `or`.

Comment: So, it's for value and/or type-checking?

Comment: thanks! to round-out this answer, the '`props: Props`' was also a `Flow` thing: it's annotating the type `Props` to the actual `props`